# Expression accessing attribute in number using getter method

Tags: java, jstl, expression, el

One of my client to integrate provide an XML with attribute name "_1", "_2" ... etc.
e.g.

```
<element _1="attr1" _2="attr2">
```

using JAXB to generate the class, the getter method of the attribute will be get1() and get2()

However in my JSP pages, using JSTL and EL, sure I cannot access the value through

```
${variable.1}
```

How can I access the value using EL correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to access the value through `variable.1`?

Comment: Sure, the JSP won't compile with error ${variable.1} contains invalid expression(s):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this notation:

```
${variable.["1"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an external binding file to rename the property generate by JAXB:

**schema.xsd**

Below is a sample XML schema based on your post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="element1">
        <complexType>
            <attribute name="_1" type="string" />
            <attribute name="_2" type="string" />
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

**binding.xml**

An external binding file is used to customize how Java classes are generated from the XML schema.  Below we'll use an external binding file to rename the generated properties.

```
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:attribute[@name='_1']">
            <jaxb:property name="one"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:attribute[@name='_2']">
            <jaxb:property name="two"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

Below is an example of how you reference the binding file when using the XJC tool.

```
xjc -b binding.xml schema.xsd
```

**Element1**

Below is what the generated class will look like:

```
package forum12259754;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "element1")
public class Element1 {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "_1")
    protected String one;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "_2")
    protected String two;

    public String getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public void setOne(String value) {
        this.one = value;
    }

    public String getTwo() {
        return two;
    }


    public void setTwo(String value) {
        this.two = value;
    }

}
```